# How to exit gracefully from a while loop when CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() is used

Tags: c#, cancellation-token, cancellationtokensource

I have the following program written in dotnet 6:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Console.CancelKeyPress += (object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) =>
{
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
};

await DoAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

Console.WriteLine("Finished!");

async Task DoAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test!");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

When I press "Ctrl + C" the program exits with the following error code:
*"Program.exe exited with code -1073741510"*. *"Finished!"* is never written to the screen.

I cannot understand what exactly happens but it seems that *cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()* throws an exception and the program finishes with error. As far as I understand, when cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() is called cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested is set to true and no exception should be thrown.

What is the reason the applicatiion to finish with exception and how can I gracefully exit the application when the user presses *"Ctrl + C"*?

I googled a lot but couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Ctrl+C` kills the application. As the [CancelKeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress?view=net-7.0) documentation explains, handling the event won't prevent termination.

To avoid termination you need to set `ConsoleCancelEventArgs.Cancel` to `true`

```
Console.CancelKeyPress += (object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) =>
{
    e.Cancel=true;
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
};
```

Comment: @canton7 I removed that. I was following the documentation looking for extra examples and remarks regarding `I googled a lot but couldn't find the answer.`

Answer (score 4):

(Not a proper answer, but too long for a comment).

Apart from the main issue, which Panagiotis Kanavos described, you'll hit a problem where your application takes up to a second to cancel, because the `Task.Delay` doesn't know about the `CancellationToken`.

The solution is to embrace exceptions as a cancellation mechanism:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Console.CancelKeyPress += (object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) =>
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
};

try
{
    await DoAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
}

Console.WriteLine("Finished!");

async Task DoAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // We'll just let Task.Delay throw an exception when the token is cancelled
        // If we were doing more work in here, we'd call
        // token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() as a suitable point
        Console.WriteLine("Test!");
        await Task.Delay(1000, token);
    }
}
```